# HTTPArty/Rails: How to handle the Response array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

I am calling an API that returns an array of JSON objects and I cant seem to properly access each element. This is a sample return value of the API call

```
[{"param1":1,"param2":"blah1"},
{"param1":2,"param2":"blah2"},
{"param1":3,"param2":"blah3"}]
```

Here is me trying to call the API and print the first JSON response object's parameter

```
result = HTTParty.get('http://randomapi.com',query: options)
@a = result[0]['param1']
# puts "#{result}"
puts "#{@a}"
```

Doing this prints nothing. I know I am successfully accessing the URL because result will print the correct information.

I got information on how to access the JSON response through this URL
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty

**Edit**:
After reading comments below, I realized that the API call is returning a content type of text/html and parsing the text/html isnt working because the response is also returning the following header below the expected value. Is there any way to remove this without going into the string itself and stripping it out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="GetRankingList.aspx?pvptype=1&amp;sid=1&amp;tm=20130821160000&amp;auth=77c9b582c3aed3d3974400cfb118fe4b" id="form1">
            <div class="aspNetHidden">
                <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZLSAAAtd4/lj1u6b0GjPWM+p3i9tqI6sq+xDrRw2cAv3" />
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the API returns a response with a *Content-Type* different from *application/json*. You can check that by printing:

```
puts result.content_type
```

If so, the *HTTParty* parser may be interpreting the response as a plain text; And, thus, the code `result[0]['param1']` evaluates to `nil`  Maybe you can try to parse the desired value into `@a` with:

```
@a = JSON.parse(result)[0]['param1']
```

Don't forget to require the json library

```
require 'json'
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, you helped me realize that it isnt returning the proper JSON format. I tried your solution but it doesnt work in this case. I give more details in the edit I just made

Comment: I don't know the particulars of the API you're using. Maybe the API isn't correct, or maybe you could call it in a way that it only returns the expected _json_ (without extra _html_). If you finally decide to strip the header out, you can use: `result[0...result.index('<!DOCTYPE')]`. Cheers!

Comment: I decided to just strip the header. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

when accessing json with format

```
require 'json'
result = JSON.parse('[{"param1":1,"param2":"blah1"},{"param1":2,"param2":"blah2"}, {"param1":3,"param2":"blah3"}]')
@a = result[0]["param1"]
puts @a
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the **parsed_response** from the result.

```
@parsed = JSON.parse(result.parsed_response)
```